# Excel Letter Plus Number Format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having a problem figuring out a way to force a certain format on a specific column.

What I"m dealing with is a spreadsheet I use to track inventory. It's used by several people and as a result, location formats are inconsistent.

(eg: A1, A01, A-1, A-01)

This makes sorting a bit of a Pain, having A1 above A10, rather than A1,A2. I want it to fix it so that no matter what is typed, it is corrected to a Letter+2 digit number format (A01).

Thanks in advance

Comment: by formatting, you can't auto-correct a typed in value, just change its display format. Anything that starts with a letter is considered a text by Excel, and no formatting will be applied in the sense you want it.

Comment: You will need to use the Worksheet_Change event in vba to do it.

Comment: I'll see if perhaps a vba script will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible within the type-in column.

- You could add an *extra (helper) column* that contains the formula that splits out the pieces of your string, formats each one accordingly, and puts them nicely together.
- if all your strings start with A, you could just tell everyone to *drop the A* (and the dash), and simply enter a number (but maybe you just gave an example)
- You could have *two* columns, one for the the alpha part, and one for the number
- you could write a *macro* that analyzes whatever they type in and does the sorting. But from experience, there is no macro in the world that can handle all absurd variations a user could potentially come up with - they will always find a variation that breaks it.

Comment: Another thought, look for ways to use pull-down menus to select the entry or pieces of it rather than entering it free-form.  Also, include format hints for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B As Range, s As String
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    If Intersect(Target, B) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    s = Target.Value
    If Len(s) <> 3 Then GoTo fixit
    If Not Left(s, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then GoTo fixit
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(s, 2, 2)) Then GoTo fixit
    Exit Sub
fixit:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "A00"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This sample macro monitors and corrects entries to column **B**.  If the entries are valid, they are left alone.  If an entry is invalid, it is replace by ***A00***.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to check the value and the checking logic was not too complex this could be done with standard Excel data validation. However, since you would like to reformat the value to be correct, you will need to use VBA or Visual Studio Tools for Office. The following is a simple VBA macro that does what you want.

The magic happens when the *Worksheet_Change* event gets fired. For the sake of the example I assume you are entering single values in the first column. The *CorrectPartNo* function does the heavy lifting. It analyses the value entered and returns a correctly formatted value or nothing to indicate there was a validation error (it only checks for maximum length). The processing works with your example, but it probably too simple for the real world. It could be easily enhanced with regular expression or other similarly powerful processing.

The event handler continues by either updating the cell with the correctly formatted part number or it makes the value entered by the user bold and red to indicate an error.

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim NewValue As String

    If (Target.Column = 1 And Target.Count = 1) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewValue = CorrectPartNo(Target.Value)
        If (Len(NewValue) = 0) Then
            Target.Font.Color = vbRed
            Target.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            Target.Value = NewValue
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Function CorrectPartNo(PartNo As String)
    Dim StartPartNo As String
    Dim EndPartNo As String
    Dim EndPartNoPosition As Integer

    StartPartNo = Left(PartNo, 1)
    If (Mid(PartNo, 2, 1) = "-") Then
        If (Len(PartNo) > 4) Then
            CorrectPartNo = ""
            Exit Function
        Else
            EndPartNoPosition = 3
        End If
    Else
        If (Len(PartNo) > 3) Then
            CorrectPartNo = ""
            Exit Function
        Else
            EndPartNoPosition = 2
        End If
    End If
    EndPartNo = Right("0" + Mid(PartNo, EndPartNoPosition), 2)

    CorrectPartNo = StartPartNo + EndPartNo
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Data Validation, with understandable prompts and messages.  The data validation formula, (assuming you want upper case for the letters) would be:

```
=AND(CODE(A1)>=65,CODE(A1)<=90,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>=48,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))<=57,CODE(MID(A1,3,1))>=48,CODE(MID(A1,3,1))<=57)
```